# How do you list installed meta packages on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, yaourt

I'd like to list all meta packages that I installed.

- Installed with `pikaur` or `pacman`
- operating system is Arch Linux

## Problem

When I install `plasma-meta` and run `pacman -Qg`, I can only see `plasma`. This is, of course, the expected behavior given for the manual entry for the query `Q` parameter `g`.

## Desired outcome

`plasma-meta`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pacman -Qqe | grep meta` should do the trick.

- `-q` suppresses the package version
- `-e` filters explicitly installed packages (no dependencies)
- `grep` filters the meta packages, assuming they follow the naming convention

`-g` does not help you here, because `plasma-meta` is not a package group, but a metapackage.

#### Groups vs. Metapackages

*Groups* and *metapackages* are a solutions to a similar problem, but technically they are very different:

- A group is a logical group of packages. When you install a group, each package that is contained in the group gets installed. Groups are a concept supported by your package manager
- A metapackage is an empty package (i.e. no files are installed) that depends on a bunch of packages. When a metapackage is installed, each dependency gets installed. This does not need special support from the package manager

Because metapackages look just like normal packages to pacman, you have to rely on the naming convention with `[name]-meta`.

Answer (score 0):

`pacman -Qqm` lists all foreign packages installed from AUR.
`pacman -Qqe` lists packages that were explicitely installed with pacman.